# How to fetch multiple API using typescript in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-masonry

I have a list of urls, I want to fetch all of them and to return the images found in all these APIs so I can render it in react component using react-responsive-masonry. I have made my function in javascript but I am not sure how to write it in typescript and also I don't know how to render it in my component.
Here's my function

```
var photos_info = [];
async function get_photos(urls) {
  var promises = urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((y) => y.json()));
  await Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    photos_info = results;
    return photos_info;
  });

  return photos_info;
}
```

I want to render it in src in my component

```
<ResponsiveMasonry columnsCountBreakPoints={columnsCountBreakPoints}>
      <Masonry gutter={4}>
        {
          <img src={} />
        }
      </Masonry>
    </ResponsiveMasonry>
```

**Edit**
Another method using **useState and useEffect**

```
const [photosList, setPhotosList] = useState<any>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const photosPromises = urls.map((url) =>
      fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())
    );
    Promise.all(photosPromises).then((data) => {
      setPhotosList(data);
    });
  }, []);
  console.log("hi", photosList);
```

I tried to render a simple one just to see what is inside

```
 <div>
      {photosList.map((photo: any) => {
        return <pre>{JSON.stringify(photo)}</pre>;
      })}
    </div>
```

but it gives me this error **Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Comment: Your code to call the APIs look mostly good, aside from the fact that you can just `return Promise.all` and don't need another `.then()` on that line. I think your issue might be in how you can do async stuff in your react component, and the answer to that is probably just `useEffect` ?

Comment: Assuming you use functional component, I would suggest you find a tutorial that explains how to process API calls with useEffect and useState.

Comment: Thank you I will search about useEffect.

Comment: @Evert can you check the edit. now when I console.log(photosList) it is printed twice one undefined and the other is the array, I don't know how to avoid that and also I don't know how to loop on PhotosList as it gives me an error that it is not defined.

Comment: Your component renders once with empty data, and then long after that, the promise resolves and it calls setPhotosList. Your component needs to check for the empty data case and show a loading or empty state, or you should initiate state to an empty array `useState([])` if you prefer

Comment: I tried this useState([]) and it doesn't give me error however it doesn't do what I want. I want to load the photos once the page is open so I don't need it empty in any case, what shall I do?

Comment: @MennaT-AllahMagdy the way react works is if something happens asynchronously you render twice. Once with and once without the data. You have to deal with this situation.

Comment: @Evert thank you for clarification. At the moment it renders the images correctly but takes some time, Is there a way I can make it render fastly or maybe preload the images before the page is opened?

Comment: @MennaT-AllahMagdy don't ask multiple questions, open a new stackoverlow question and describe your problem clearly.